# Limited Number of Connections When Using CHUNKED encoding

Tags: java, http-headers, axis

I'm using the Axis 1.x SOAP Framework in one of my web service clients. During our early testing for the application, it turns out that if we use the default HTTP 1.0 standards (Without CHUNKED encoding), and when the received SOAP envelope is huge, I end up with an invalid XML exception. This is why I have added the client-config.wsdd file, and set the CHUNKED property as part  of the HTTP Request Headers. This has solved my problem.

This however has caused yet another problem:
When using the CHUNKED encoding, and when making web service calls using my client, I am limited to ONLY "2" simultaneous calls (Each call needs around 1 minute to return a response). So before any of the two web services returns a response, any additional calls are "put on hold".

My question is: is there a way to override this behavior, while making sure that I'd still be using CHUNKED encoding, which helped solve my earlier problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally come around this problem by setting the following value:
AxisProperties.setProperty(DefaultCommonsHTTPClientProperties.MAXIMUM_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOST_PROPERTY_KEY, maxConnections);